# How to separate meta tags inside header

Tags: php, html, newline

Inside my header the html tags are not separated by new lines.

For example:

```
<? if(){
     echo 'meta title';
   }
   if(something){
     echo 'meta desc';
   } ?>
```

The Mozilla browser does not break lines between meta's

Any ideas?

Comment: Those line breaks are not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put newline characters at the end of each line to explicitly end the line. The newline character is `\n`. Notice I changed your single quotes to double quotes as single quotes would cause the `\` not to escape the `n` and literally print `\n` to the page instead of a newline character.

```
   <? if(){
     echo "<title>Website Title</title>\n";
   }
   if(something){
     echo "<meta description=\"desciption\" />\n";
   } ?>
```

See the [PHP manual for more on special characters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: One more thing, I have a php code just before everything which sets variables, etc (but does not echo anything)... Looking at the header in mozilla, I get an empty row there. Any ideas how to remove that?

Comment: or you can use `PHP_EOL` constant instead of "\n" - this constant is OS-aware, so on Windows it will be `CRLF` ("\r\n")

Comment: @webmasters That empty row is just a figment of Mozilla's imagination. The closing PHP tag actually strips a new line character immediately after it so that shouldn't even be possible.

Comment: Oups, I should have edited the Q better - How do I add a new line if I have <title>Website Title</title> How to add this?